# sf::Event::Keypressed not working inside of poll event loop -SFML-2.5.1

Tags: c++, c++17, sfml, codelite

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/System.hpp>

int main(){
    
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480),  "Window");    

       while (window.isOpen())
        {
            sf::Event event;
            while (window.pollEvent(event))
            {
                switch (event.type)
                {
                    case sf::Event::Closed:
                        window.close(); break;
                    
                    case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                        std::cout << event.key.code;
                        break;
                    
                }
            }
         }
 return 0;
}
```

I get a bunch of warnings like this `enumeration value 'MouseLeft' not handled in switch`

I tried putting it in an `if` statement instead of a `switch` that got rid of the warnings but it still will not output `event.key.code` i could only get it to work when I put it outside of the `pollevent(event)` loop but then letters werent picked up.

Comment: This piece of code does not help because comparing to some sample code of mine, it should work. Please provide reproducible code.

Comment: Make a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `<< std::flush;` after your `cout`s and you will see the key codes. Otherwise they will not be printed until SFML main loop is left (not when interrupted but when closed gracefully using x button).